# WebdriverIO throw error after NPM version update

Tags: npm, webdriver-io

I just update all the package and NPM versions in a webdriverIO project but now its not working throwing following error

ERROR @wdio/local-runner: Failed launching test session: Error: Couldn't initialise "@wdio/allure-reporter".
[0-0] Error: Cannot find module 'csv-stringify/sync'

I tried all the possible combinations, like removing the allure report downgrading the version, etc but no success.
here is my packagesJson

```
    "homepage": "https://github.com/",
      "dependencies": {
      "@wdio/cli": "^7.16.10",
    "allure-commandline": "^2.13.8",
    "csv": "^6.0.4",
    "csv-stringify": "^6.0.4",
    "prettier": "^2.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.4",
    "@babel/register": "^7.16.0",
    "@wdio/allure-reporter": "^7.16.10",
    "@wdio/dot-reporter": "^7.16.6",
    "@wdio/junit-reporter": "^7.16.6",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^7.16.10",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^7.16.6",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^7.16.9",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "chromedriver": "^96.0.0",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^7.2.2"
  }
}
```

npm -v
8.1.4

Comment: Try removing node modules and package-lock file and remove the cave and csv- stringify option from the package .json

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by updating the node version and building the project from scratch